# My home page is still showing link "localhost"

Tags: links, homepage, localhost

Please I have created my site and hosted it..all links and pages are working fine, but when I want to go back to homepage from another page it creates an error,

I discovered the page address is still "localhost/name...How can I change this.
I inspected the menu bar button for homepage and discovered the link it is pointing to is "localhost" rather than the actual homepage.

Comment: Find out how that button is created and proceed to fix the issue.

Comment: The redirection at the top of the question (This Question is an exact duplicate of...) leads to nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found a solution..went to my wordpress dashboard>appaearnce>menu. Selected menu to edit, then I went to the homepage item on the menu> custo m link...Then I found the problem, changed the address there from localhost/ to my website address.

Well a newbie like me just learnt something new. More power to this forums. Thanks guys.